# Troubles with string and double, get another number after equating

Tags: c++, string, char, int, ostream

After calculating a number, I need to get several digits of this one. I cast it to string, and print a digit, but in one piece of code, it works correct (prints only one digit), but after I equate it to another variable, the program prints 2 digits.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>    
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    time_t seconds;
    int res = 0;
    seconds = time(NULL);
    double nump = seconds;
    cout.precision(45);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        nump = nump /10;
    }
    std::ostringstream strs;
    strs.precision(55);
    strs << nump;
    std::string str = strs.str();
    cout << str[str.size() - 9] << endl; // here we get a gidit from the string (e.g. 5)
    res = str[str.size() - 9];
    cout << res << endl; // here we get a number (e.g. 49)
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I cant understand whats going on. Please help!

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Re: "I cast it to string" -- there are no casts in this code. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because here

```
res = str[str.size() - 9];
```

You are storing the value of a `char` in an `int`. Printing the same value as `int` can have different results when you send it to `std::cout` than when you print it as `char`. For integers [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) operator is called, while for chars [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) operator is called instead.

In your example, you probably have a value of `'1'` (which is `49` in ASCII). When you print it as a `char` it prints `1`, and when you print it as an `int`, it prints `49`.

One way to solve this problem is to make `int res` be a `char` instead.